# How do I reliably generate checksums for gallery images in iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, image

I'm building an app on Android and iOS and am curious about generating checksums that match across the two platforms. I need to generate checksums for gallery images. I notice that when I access images in Android, they are in JPEG format but iOS seems convert all images to PNG when it is accessed from the device gallery. This happens for two identical photos copied to both devices from my laptop. The original photo is a JPEG.

**Question: How do I generate matching checksums for images in both platforms?** I understand that people may not be developers on both platforms but feel free to share your knowledge individually as well.

Answer (score 0):

for android you can use this

public static String calculateCRCcheckSum(String filepath) {

```
String crc = "00000000";
InputStream fi;
CRC32 gCRC = null;
try {
    fi = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filepath));
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 64];
    int gByte = 0;
    gCRC = new CRC32();
    try {

    while ((gByte = fi.read(buf)) > 0) {
        gCRC.update(buf, 0, gByte);
    }
    fi.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return crc;
    }
    try {
    fi.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    return crc;
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return crc;
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return crc;
}

finally {
    // Log.d("Zip", "value is " + Long.toHexString(gCRC.getValue()));
    // Log.d("Zip", "value in decfimal is " + gCRC.getValue());
}
crc = gCRC.getValue() + "";
return crc;

}
```

for android you can use this